# SQL Server: join query

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 3 tables (forms, fields, fieldsperform):

```
forms   |   fields   |   fieldsperform
  id    |      id    |          formid
 group  |    group   |        fieldid
 name   |    name
```

What I want is to add in fieldsperform the same forms-fields couples but for another group. This is what I have now:

**Forms:**

```
id   |  group  |  name
 0   |  groupA |  formA
 1   |  groupA |  formB
 2   |  groupB |  formA
 3   |  groupB |  formB
```

**Fields**

```
id  |  group  |  name
0   |  groupA | fieldA
1   |  groupA | fieldB
2   |  groupA | fieldC
3   |  groupB | fieldA
4   |  groupB | fieldB
5   |  groupB | fieldC
```

**FieldsPerForm**

```
formid   |   fieldid
  0      |      0       (formA - fieldA)
  0      |      2       (formA - fieldC)
  1      |      1       (formB - fieldB)
  1      |      2       (formB - fieldC)
```

And I want to insert the same couples but for the groupB. So I want to insert :

```
formid   |   fieldid
  2      |      3       (formA - fieldA)
  2      |      5       (formA - fieldC)
  3      |      4       (formB - fieldB)
  3      |      5       (formB - fieldC)
```

**Logic:**

Check the couples in `FieldsPerForm`. The first couple is (0,0). formid = 0 is formA in the `Forms` table. In the `Forms` table the formA form for groupB has id = 2 so the formid of the first couple is 2. Then do the same for the `Fields` table and so on

Comment: Your logic for forming group B pairs is not clear to me.  Why do we not have `(2, 4)` as a group B pair?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen (2,4) pair for group B is (formA,fieldB), this pair doesnt exist for Group A .

Comment: Why does 0,1 not exist for group A?

Comment: Why is there no (formA - fieldB)?

Comment: Please edit your question with the exact logic for forming pairs in both groups.  There is no sort of when writing a query; if you can't give logic, then you can't query it.

Comment: why should exist? It doesnt mean that all fields must be used in formA. formA has 2 fields: fieldA and fieldC , formB has 2 fields fieldB and fieldC. FieldB is not used in formA or formB

Comment: Please post DDL and insert statements for the data to make life easy for people trying to help you

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the pairs for groupA are already existing. I want to create the same pairs for groupB but with the appropriate ids

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO FieldsPerForm(formid, fieldid)
SELECT fo.id, fi.id from 
(SELECT fo.name as foname, fi.name as finame
    FROM FieldsPerForm fpf 
    JOIN Forms fo ON (fpf.formid = fo.id)
    JOIN Fields fi ON (fpf.fieldid = fi.id)) datatbl 
JOIN forms fo ON (fo.name = datatbl.foname)
JOIN fields fi ON (fi.name = datatbl.foname)
WHERE datatbl.group = 'groupA' AND fo.group = 'groupB' 
and fi.group = 'groupB';
```

Comment: Yes, the same couples but I want the ids for groupB

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query

```
DECLARE @Forms AS TABLE(id INT, [group]  VARCHAR(10),  name VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Forms
VALUES
('0','groupA','formA'),
('1','groupA','formB'),
('2','groupB','formA'),
('3','groupB','formB')

DECLARE @Fields AS TABLE(id INT, [group]  VARCHAR(10),  name VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @Fields
VALUES
('0','groupA','fieldA'),
('1','groupA','fieldB'),
('2','groupA','fieldC'),
('3','groupB','fieldA'),
('4','groupB','fieldB'),
('5','groupB','fieldC')

DECLARE @FieldsPerForm TABLE(formid INT,   fieldid INT)
INSERT INTO @FieldsPerForm 
VALUES
(0,0), --  (formA - fieldA)
(0,2), --  (formA - fieldC)
(1,1), --  (formB - fieldB)
(1,2)  --  (formB - fieldC)

INSERT INTO @FieldsPerForm
SELECT FRM_B.id , FLD_B.id 
FROM @Forms FRM_A 
    INNER JOIN @Fields FLD_A ON FRM_A.[group] = FLD_A.[group] 
    INNER JOIN @FieldsPerForm FF ON FF.fieldid = FLD_A.id AND FF.formid = FRM_A.id
    INNER JOIN @Forms FRM_B ON FRM_A.name = FRM_B.name AND FRM_B.[group] = 'groupB'
    INNER JOIN @Fields FLD_B ON FLD_A.name = FLD_B.name AND FLD_B.[group] = 'groupB'
WHERE 
    FRM_A.[group] ='groupA'
ORDER BY 
    FF.formid, FF.fieldid
```

Result:

```
id          id
----------- -----------
2           3
2           5
3           4
3           5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO FieldsPerForm
(
    formid
    , fieldid
)

SELECT
    FO.id
    , FI.id
FROM
    Forms FO
    JOIN Fields FI ON
        FO.[group] = FI.[group]
        AND
            (
                (FO.name = 'formA' AND FI.name = 'fieldA')
                OR (FO.name = 'formA' AND FI.name = 'fieldC')
                OR (FO.name = 'formB' AND FI.name = 'fieldB')
                OR (FO.name = 'formB' AND FI.name = 'fieldC')
            )
WHERE FO.[group] = 'groupB' -- optional WHERE clause
```

Comment: I am not looking for a solution with static names. There are a lot of fields and forms so is not going to work

Comment: "formA has 2 fields: fieldA and fieldC" - this isn't clear from the data. If you removed the WHERE clause, or altered it to `<> 'groupA'`, it would replicate the current pattern for as many groups as you have.

Comment: It is clear. In the FieldsPerForm there are only 2 pairs for formA : formA - fieldA and formA - fieldC

Comment: If the logic needs to come from the FieldsPerForm table, I don't think you can get a simpler solution than the one I've provided above. There are 4 combinations, and there's no logic to these combinations, other than the fact that they already exist in the table.

Comment: Thats true. I just want to copy the existing. You can see the algorithm I want in my edited post

Comment: Yes, I think based on that algorithm the query I've already posted is the best you can get. You're essentially asking for a replica of a set of combinations that have no inherent logic themselves (at least not in the data), so the only way is to copy every condition. If you alter the WHERE clause as I mentioned above (`<> 'groupA'`), how does that suit your requirements?

Comment: The problem with your query is that is not going to work if groupA has formC also.. its not dynamic

Comment: I think that's part of the issue - there's no logic for formC in FieldsPerForm, and this is where your logic needs to come from, so it's not possible to put something together for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (you can use the code as a stored procedure, MSSQL):

```
 DECLARE @SourceGroup varchar(max), @DestinationGroup varchar(max)

 SET @SourceGroup = 'groupA'
 SET @DestinationGroup = 'groupB'

INSERT INTO FieldsPerForm (FormID, FieldID)

SELECT  FO1.ID as FormIDNew,
        FI1.ID as FieldIDNew
FROM dbo.FieldsPerForm FPF 
    JOIN 
        dbo.Forms FO ON FPF.FormID = FO.ID and FO.[Group] = @SourceGroup
    JOIN
        dbo.Fields FI ON FPF.FieldID = FI.ID and FI.[Group] = @SourceGroup
    JOIN 
        dbo.Forms FO1 ON FO1.Name = FO.Name and FO1.[Group] = @DestinationGroup and FO.[Group] = @SourceGroup
    JOIN 
        dbo.Fields FI1 ON FI1.Name = FI.Name and FI1.[Group] = @DestinationGroup and FI.[Group] = @SourceGroup
```